# Modification of configuration file using sed

Tags: linux, mongodb, bash, sed

mongod.conf file

```
 # mongod.conf
 # for documentation of all options, see:
 # http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/
 # Where and how to store data.
   storage:
   dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
   journal:
   enabled: true
 #  engine:
 #  mmapv1:
 #  wiredTiger:
 # where to write logging data.
   systemLog:
   destination: file
   logAppend: true
   path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
 # network interfaces
   net:
   port: 27017
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
 #processManagement:
 #security:
 #operationProfiling:
 #replication:
 #sharding:
 ## Enterprise-Only Options  
 #auditLog: 
 #snmp:
```

This is the mongoDB configuration file I have, I need to Update keys in the file like this,

```
port: 27017 
bindIp: 0.0.0.0 
#security: 
keyFile:/opt/mongodb/keyfile 
authorization: enabled 
#replication: 
replSetName: mongoreplica1
```

How can I do this using bash script?

Comment: You haven't mentioned what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Technext I tried sed -i 's/^\(bindIp\s*=\s*\).*$/\10.0.0.0/' /etc/mongod.conf, but it is not updating

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have tried -e option also, but it is not updating

Comment: Not `-e`, but `-E`. Try `sed -i -E 's/^( *bindIp *: *).*$/\10.0.0.0/'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  root@VMtest:/opt# sed -i -E 's/^\(bindIp\s*=\s*\).*$/\10.0.0.0/' /etc/mongod.conf
sed: -e expression #1, char 34: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS                      This is the output I got after using -E

Comment: Are you on Mac? Try `sed -i '' 's/^\( *bindIp *: *\).*$/\10.0.0.0/'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew root@VMtest:/opt# sed -i -E sed -E 's/^( *bindIp *: *).*$/\10.0.0.0/'
Usage: sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]...

  -n, --quiet, --silent
                 suppress automatic printing of pattern space
  -e script, --expression=script
                 add the script to the commands to be executed
  -f script-file, --file=script-file
                 add the contents of script-file to the commands to be executed
  --follow-symlinks
                 follow symlinks when processing in place
  -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

Comment: I'd put keys to update into a file named `update` and run `awk '/^ +[^#]/ { cfg[$1] = $2 } END{ for (key in cfg) { print key, cfg[key] } }' mongod.conf update` but idk if this shomehow breaks the config, can you give it a try ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not on Mac , accessing Linux VM through Cygwin

Comment: If not on Mac, `sed -i 's/^\( *bindIp *: *\).*$/\10.0.0.0/'` should be enough.

Comment: @oguzismail I will try that and update you

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew successfully executed

Comment: @jww Ok , you can give suggestions , but why you down voted my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may fix the `sed` command using

```
sed -i 's/^\( *bindIp *: *\).*/\10.0.0.0/'
```

The BRE POSIX pattern `^\( *bindIp *: *\).*` matches

- `^` - start of string
- `\( *bindIp *: *\)` - Capturing group #1 (referred to with `\1` from the RHS): zero or more spaces, `bindIp`, zero or more spaces, `:` and zero or more spaces
- `.*` - rest of the line

Comment: One more thing is how I can add                                                                
#security: 
keyFile:/opt/mongodb/keyfile 
authorization: enabled 
#replication: 
replSetName: mongoreplica1

Comment: @JIMITH Probably you want something like `sed -i 's,^ *#security: *$,  #security: keyFile:/opt/mongodb/keyfile\n  authorization: enabled\n#replication:\n  replSetName: mongoreplica1,'`. See [this demo](http://rextester.com/CSAP24498).

Comment: root@VMtest:/opt# sed 's,^ *#security: *$, #security: keyFile:/opt/mongodb/keyfile\n authorization: enabled\n#replication:\n replSetName: mongoreplica1,' /etc/mongod.conf
# mongod.conf

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0


#processManagement:

 #security: keyFile:/opt/mongodb/keyfile
 authorization: enabled
#replication:
 replSetName: mongoreplica1

Comment: Showing updated contents in the terminal , but the file is not updating

Comment: Come on, you did not use the inline option, `-i`. Together with your code, `sed -i 's,^ *#security: *$, #security: keyFile:/opt/mongodb/keyfile\n authorization: enabled\n#replication:\n replSetName: mongoreplica1,' /etc/mongod.conf`

Comment: Successful, I am very happy with your solution for this issue. Have a good day.